# What is the relation between Rössler attractor and thin accretion discs (like in the movie Interstellar)?

Tags: astrophysics, chaos-theory, stellar-physics

Is there any relationship between the [Rössler attractor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%B6ssler_attractor) and thin accretion disks, like the accretion disk(s) in the movie *Interstellar*?

Comment: What makes you think there is?

Comment: Well, both present trajectories. So my assumption was that accretion discs can be somehow approximated by Rössler attractors. Obviously not the case. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any, the accretion disc is assumed to actually just be a disc in the equatorial plane like the rings of Saturn, it only appears distorted due to strong [gravitational lensing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_lens) of the light it emits, see my answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/151318/59406). And their appearance isn't even the same, the [Rossler attractor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%B6ssler_attractor) has a cusp or bulge in only one direction out of the disc-shaped region:

[image]

Whereas the apparent visual shape of the accretion disc has two bulges above and below the equatorial region, and the portion that actually appears to be in the equatorial plane doesn't extend around a full 360 degrees:

[image]

Comment: Very pretty! If I fly a Moebius trajectory in the disk, can I go back in time? ;-)