# Interstellar Movie: Black hole shown in the movie

Tags: visible-light, black-holes

In the interstellar movie, the black hole shown has a ring of light orbiting around it. From what I know, (correct me if I'm wrong) that light is unable to escape the gravity of the blackhole and therefore is orbiting the blackhole. If it is unable to escape, why can we see that light?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does this depiction of a black hole in the movie Interstellar mean?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/148567/)

Comment: see also http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/137837

Comment: If it was actually light orbiting the black hole, then you wouldn't see it, because the light would be orbiting instead of actually reaching your eyes.

Comment: That is light emitted from the accretion disc around the black hole. As it gets closer to the black hole, it gets hotter. As we all know, hot things glow, emitting light.