# Black hole as it is portrayed in the Interstellar film

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, spacetime, event-horizon, popular-science

In the film Interstellar, a character called Cooper travels into a black hole and falls straight into the so-called "tesseract". The tesseract is a 5-dimensional portal in which the ordinary time of 4d spacetime is spatial and can be accessed like an axis on a graph,

[image: Tesseract]

Was this scene based on science or fiction?

Comment: No, I don't remember that scene because I haven't seen it, and I don't know what "access time like an axis on a graph" means. Please don't make having watched a movie a prerequisite for understanding a question, but include all necessary details in the question itself.

Comment: @ACuriousMind In the (painful to watch) film, the main character can physically access different points in time of his daughter's bedroom, simply by moving from one room in a sequence to another. I vote to close this question; it goes without saying this particular aspect of the film is far removed from any mainstream physics.

Comment: I asked this question Because I read article that claim 
> Interstellar : Discovered the Gravitational Waves before everyone else.
https://medium.com/the-cinéphilia/interstellar-discovered-the-gravitational-waves-before-everyone-else-a505b508aedd#.f8o4xkn46

Comment: Yes, the fictional scene about fictional characters was fictional.

Comment: There is another scene in the film that was interesting،

In that scene a teacher claims:
Apollo missions were faked to bankrupt the Soviet Union!

Comment: Kip Stephen Thorne (born June 1, 1940) is an
American theoretical physicist , known for his contributions in gravitational physics and
astrophysics. He continues to do scientific research and scientific consulting, most notably for the Christopher Nolan film,
Interstellar
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kip_Thorne

Comment: Kip Thorne's help on the film does not mean that it is any less fictional.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the "tesseract" scene was completely fictional.

This movie is notable for its realism in some scenes, due in part to Kip Thorne's involvement as a consultant. In particular, the depiction of the black hole when seen from the outside is accurate in some respects. (See the answers [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/148567/what-does-this-depiction-of-a-black-hole-in-the-movie-interstellar-mean?rq=1) for details.) The scenes with the wormhole also depict optical effects from the bending of space-time in a realistic manner, though the existence of the wormhole itself is not realistic. New rendering software was developed for those scenes.

However, a major theme of the movie is that physics can't tell us what can be found inside a black hole. In the movie, aliens created the tesseract there so that Cooper could send messages back in time, but that's completely fictional.

Answer (score 0):

> In the film Interstellar, a character called Cooper travels into a black hole and falls straight into the so-called "tesseract".

A [tesseract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesseract) is a *"four-dimensional analog of the cube; the tesseract is to the cube as the cube is to the square"*

> The tesseract is a 5-dimensional portal in which the ordinary time of 4d spacetime is spatial and can be accessed like an axis on a graph. Was this scene based on science or fiction?

Fiction. Absolute total fiction. The problem with [interstellar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interstellar_(film)) is that it was billed as having robust bona-fide science, but actually it didn't. Google on [Interstellar pseudoscience](https://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=EUM_VY2-Juiq8wfv_oCgDA&gws_rd=ssl#q=interstellar+pseudoscience) to find out more. And I'm afraid this isn't the first time Kip Thorne has peddled "woo" under false pretences. See [this article](https://plus.maths.org/content/time-travel-allowed) where he's promoting time travel.Wormholes are pseudoscience too.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48863/discussion-on-answer-by-john-duffield-black-hole-as-it-is-portrayed-in-the-inter).